# HttpCookie - Unable to update existing cookie ASP.NET [Google Chrome]

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, httpcookie, samesite

1. Codes below is to update value into existing cookie.
2. These codes working fine but now the I have no idea why it breaks and  unable to update the latest value into cookie. (Cookie keep showing first assigned value).
3. Example flows:
   a)   The first assigned value in cookie is "abc".
   b)  Update "123" as latest value into cookie.
   c) Read cookie but value remains "abc".
4. I have tried in Microsoft Edge where the cookie updates worked as expected but no idea why google chrome is failed to update cookie.

   ```
       string m_cookie = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
       string m_Json = string.Empty;
       HttpCookie m_httpCookie;
       FormsAuthenticationTicket m_ticket;
       m_httpCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[m_cookie];
       m_ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(m_httpCookie.Value);

       m_Json = (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserCredential1
       {
           UserName = "123",
           ExpiredAt = "123",
           AccessToken = "123",
           TokenType = "123",
       })).ToString();

       var newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(m_ticket.Version, m_ticket.Name, 
       m_ticket.IssueDate, dtNowAdd1min, false, m_Json, m_ticket.CookiePath);
       m_httpCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
       if (newticket.IsPersistent) m_httpCookie.Expires = newticket.Expiration;

       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(m_httpCookie);

       m_httpCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[m_cookie];
       m_ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(m_httpCookie.Value);
       UserCredential result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserCredential>(m_ticket.UserData);
   ```
5. I'm suspecting this happens due to Google Chrome Samesite settings?
6. Anyone have idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey there, I'm not sure of the context in which you're trying to set or read the cookie. If it's in a third-party / cross-site context then you may be impacted by the SameSite changes. We've got some debugging guidance for Chrome DevTools here: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: @rowan_m Thanks, I have tested with your link and confirmed its samesite issue. And now the cookie suddenly working fine like before because Google is temporarily rolling back Chrome’s SameSite cookie requirements due to COVID-19 outbreak. You can check out at here [link](https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/3/21207248/chrome-samesite-cookie-roll-back-update-privacy-settings)

Comment: You may need to set the `SameSite=None` and `Secure` attributes when you set the cookie. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie.samesite?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpCookie_SameSite